# Stored Procedures Difficulty

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server and I'm stuck on a problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Using the AP database create a stored procedure called `spFindInvoices` that accepts two parameters: `@NameVendor` of type `varchar` and `@BalanceLimit` of type `smallmoney`.

This procedure displays the VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDueDate and Balance of @NameVendor where the balance is greater than @BalanceLimit. If you call/test the procedure with `@NameVendor = ‘Federal Express Corporation’` and `@BalanceLimit = 0`, the following table will be displayed:

```
(my code)
USE AP;
GO

CREATE PROC spInvoices
     @NameVendor VARCHAR(50),
     @BalanceLimit SMALLMONEY
AS
    SELECT 
        VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDueDate, 
        (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal) AS Balance
    FROM 
        Invoices 
    JOIN 
        Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
    WHERE 
        @NameVendor > @BalanceLimit
GO

EXEC spFindInvoices @NameVendor = 'Federal Express Corporation',
                    @BalanceLimit = '0'
```

Comment: You are comparing a name to a balance limit. Clearly your code has issues.

Comment: `@NameVendor` should correspond to the `VendorName` right?

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: where VendorName = #vendorName and (InvoiceTotal-CreditTotal-PaymentTotal)  > @balanceLimit

Comment: This sure sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I grasp what you're asking, but if I am correct I believe you're looking for all balances above a specified amount for a specified vendor

```
USE AP;
GO

CREATE PROC spInvoices
     @NameVendor VARCHAR(50),
     @BalanceLimit SMALLMONEY
AS
    SELECT 
        VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDueDate, 
        (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal) AS Balance
    FROM 
        Invoices 
    JOIN 
        Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
    WHERE 
        @BalanceLimit > (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal)
    AND 
        @NameVendor = VendorName
GO

EXEC spFindInvoices @NameVendor = 'Federal Express Corporation',
                @BalanceLimit = '0'
```

You are comparing the VARCHAR @VendorName and the SMALLMONEY @BalanceLimit with each-other, when you should be comparing them to their corresponding values in your query

Answer (score 0):

This code should works:

```
CREATE PROC spInvoices
     @NameVendor VARCHAR(50),
     @BalanceLimit SMALLMONEY
AS
    SELECT 
        VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDueDate, 
        (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal) AS Balance
    FROM 
        Invoices 
    JOIN 
        Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
    WHERE 
        @NameVendor  = Vendors.VendorName
        (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal) > @BalanceLimit
```

But, maybe you need explicitly cast your columns: `InvoiceTotal`, `CreditTotal`, `PaymentTotal` to `smallmoney` datattytpe if that columns has other type than `smallmoney`.